# Can you name a turtle in python based of a variable?

Tags: python, variables, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

Sorry, nooby question but couldn't find anywhere if it was possible to name a turtle with a variable in its name?

**For example:**

```
Variable = 1

Turtle(Variable) = turtle.Turtle()

Turtle1.goto(0,0)
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: This is the whole point of using arrays (lists in Python), which gives you an [index] for the variable within the list. Variables with numbers directly in their names are horrible to work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be emulated with a `dict` or a `list` (as @UsernameObfuscation notes, +1):

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

variable = 1

turtles = {}  # or turtles = [] if 'variable' is only an incrementing int

turtles[variable] = Turtle()

turtles[variable].goto(100, 100)

screen = Screen()
screen.exitonclick()
```

Answer (score 0):

The line `Turtle(Variable) = turtle.Turtle()` is problematic from another point of view.

You are doing Left Hand Side assignment to a variable called Turtle, and you are giving it the value of `turtle.Turtle()`, so basically you suppose to get syntax error for that line.

On the other hand, the next code should give you the result you are looking for, but without naming the turtle:

```
Turtle = turtle.Turtle()
Turtle.goto(0,0)
```